# Is it possible to implement a shared state management for CLI applications without the need for an external database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

I want to create a CLI application and I think this question is not about a specific technology but for the sake of reproduction purposes I'm using Node with [command-line-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-commands) ( but I know there are plenty others, e.g. [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) ).

Given the following sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
const commandLineCommands = require('command-line-commands');
const commandLineUsage = require('command-line-usage');

let isRunning = false; // global state

let commandResult;

try {
    commandResult = commandLineCommands([ 'start', 'info', 'help' ]);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Invalid command.');
    process.exit(1);
}

if (commandResult.command === null || commandResult.command === 'help') {
    const commandInfo = commandLineUsage([
        { header: 'start', content: 'Sets the value to true' },
        { header: 'info', content: 'Gets the current value' },
    ]);

    console.log(commandInfo);
    process.exit(0);
}

let options;

try {
    options = commandLineArgs([], { argv: commandResult.argv });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Invalid argument.');
    process.exit(1);
}

if (commandResult.command === 'start') {
    isRunning = true;
} else if (commandResult.command === 'info') {
    console.info({ isRunning });
}
```

The boolean `isRunning` indicates a shared state. Calling the `start` command sets its value to true. But calling the `info` command obviously starts a new process and prints a new variable `isRunning` with its initial falsy value.

What is the prefered technology to keep such state? Must the CLI use an external database ( e.g. local filesystem) or are there some ways to keep the information in memory until shutdown?

Generating my own file on the system and storing this variable to it feels like an overkill to me.

Comment: Well you could try finding other running processes and communicate with them, but yes a file is the simplest solution.

Comment: The first question to answer is which invocations you want to share this state. Two calls in the same terminal? Two calls by the same user? Two calls on the same computer? Something else?

Comment: @Bergi I think two calls in the same terminal session should be the correct invocation

Answer (score 1):

An old cross-platform hack is to open a known TCP port. The first process able to open the port will get the port. All other processes trying to open the port will get an **EADDRINUSE** error:

```
const net = require('net');

const s = net.createServer();

s.on('error',() => {
    console.log('Program is already running!');

    // handle what to do here
});

s.listen(5123,'127.0.0.1',() => {
    console.log('OK');

    // run your main function here
});
```

This works in any language on any OS. There is only one thing you need to be careful of - some other program may be accidentally using the port you are using.

I originally came across this technique on the Tcl wiki: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/singleton+application.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would like to avoid duplicate comments so I'm refering to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574918/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-shared-state-management-for-cli-applications-witho#comment128274500_72600792

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a local web server.

index.js

```
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
const commandLineCommands = require('command-line-commands');
const commandLineUsage = require('command-line-usage');
var http = require('http');

let globalState = {
    isRunning: false
}

let commandResult;

try {
    commandResult = commandLineCommands([ 'start', 'info', 'help' ]);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Invalid command.');
    process.exit(1);
}

if (commandResult.command === null || commandResult.command === 'help') {
    const commandInfo = commandLineUsage([
        { header: 'start', content: 'Sets the value to true' },
        { header: 'info', content: 'Gets the current value' },
    ]);

    console.log(commandInfo);
    process.exit(0);
}

let options;

try {
    options = commandLineArgs([], { argv: commandResult.argv });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Invalid argument.');
    process.exit(1);
}

if (commandResult.command === 'start') {
    globalState.isRunning = true;
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(globalState));
        res.end();
    }).listen(9615);
} else if (commandResult.command === 'info') {
    console.info({ globalState });
}
```

index2.js

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.request({ host: "localhost", port: 9615, path: "/" }, (response) => {
    var responseData = "";

    response.on("data", (chunk) => {
        responseData += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(responseData));
    });
});

req.end();
req.on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Here the index.js is a program that holds the "shared / global state" as well as creates a web server to communicate with. Other programs such as index2.js here can make a http request and ask for the global state. You could also let other programs change the state by having index.js listen to some specific request and act accordingly.

This doesn't *have to* be done with http like this, you could also use something like [node-rpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@node-rpc/client) or [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc). I thought the easiest working example would be to do it with a local http client and server.

Either way, I think the word for what you are looking for is [Inter Process Communication (IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) or [Remote Procedure Call (RPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). I don't see why one couldn't also utilize [websockets](https://github.com/websockets/ws) as well. Child processes probably won't work here, even if you could implement some kind of parent-child process communication, because only the child processes spawned by the main process could use that.

**EDIT**

After reading your question more carefully, I think that this is just a matter of "keeping" the "console session" after start command and setting the isRunning variable.

Check this out:

```
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args');
const commandLineCommands = require('command-line-commands');
const commandLineUsage = require('command-line-usage');
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

let globalState = {
    isRunning: false
}

let commandResult;

try {
    commandResult = commandLineCommands([ 'start', 'info', 'help' ]);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Invalid command.');
    process.exit(1);
}

if (commandResult.command === null || commandResult.command === 'help') {
    const commandInfo = commandLineUsage([
        { header: 'start', content: 'Sets the value to true' },
        { header: 'info', content: 'Gets the current value' },
    ]);

    console.log(commandInfo);
    process.exit(0);
}

let options;

try {
    options = commandLineArgs([], { argv: commandResult.argv });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Invalid argument.');
    process.exit(1);
}

if (commandResult.command === 'start') {
    globalState.isRunning = true;

    while(globalState.isRunning)
    {
        let cmd = prompt(">");

        if(cmd === "exit")
            process.exit(0);
        if(cmd === "info")
            console.info({ globalState });
    }
   
} else if (commandResult.command === 'info') {
    console.info({ globalState });
}
```

Here I am using `prompt-sync` library inside a loop when the program is called with a `start` command. The "console session" is kept indefinitely until the user types `exit`. I also added and example for in case the user types `info`.

Example:

[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think this looks like a huge overkill. I just would like to store some data "during the terminal session". Maybe I should use a temporary file?

Comment: @baitendbidz Ahhh I think I get you better now, let me edit my answer.

Comment: @baitendbidz There we go, what do you think of the latest example? Is that what you were actually after?

Comment: okay, so I would have to replace `prompt(">")` with something like `prompt("What would you like to do")` but I can't map the variable `cmd` to `commandResult.argv` again, right? So I wouldn't be able to trigger the `command-line-args` / `commanderjs` workflow again

Comment: @baitendbidz You probably could! Look at this example https://github.com/tj/commander.js/#common-option-types-boolean-and-value I think it's just a matter of calling `program.parse` with `cmd` instead of `process.argv`, no? You might just have to do `cmd.split(" ")` since if you look here https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processargv process.argv is an array and not a string.

Comment: ah ok let me give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Another old hack for this is to try and create a symlink.

**Creating** symlinks are generally guaranteed to be atomic by most Unix and Unix-like OSes. Therefore there is no issue with potential race conditions using this technique (unlike creating a regular file). I presume it is also atomic on Windows (as per POSIX spec) but I'm not entirely sure:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const scriptName = process.argv[1];
const lockFile = '/tmp/my-program.lock';

try {
    fs.symlinkSync(lockFile, scriptName);

    // run your main function here

    fs.unlinkSync(lockFile);
}
catch (err) {
    console.log('Program already running');

    // handle what to do here
}
```

> Note: While **creating** symlinks are atomic, other operations on symlinks are not guaranteed to be atomic. Specifically be very careful of assuming that updating a symlink is atomic - **it is NOT**. Updating symlinks involve two operations: deleting the link and then creating the link. A second process may execute its delete operation after your process creates a symlink causing two processes to think that they're the only ones running. In the example above we delete the link **after** creating it, not before.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would like to avoid duplicate comments so I'm refering to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574918/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-shared-state-management-for-cli-applications-witho#comment128274500_72600792

Comment: So. Reading your comment form that answer you are saying that using a temporary file (symlink) is huge overkill and you think you should use a temporary file (which you said is overkill) instead?

Comment: I don't know if the code above works on all operating systems. And would you mind explaining the reasons for a symlink?

Comment: I explained it in the second paragraph. A symlink, unlike a regular file, is guaranteed to be atomic. That is, when a process is creating a symlink the device driver of the disk will not allow any other file operations to happen. Therefore it is safe to use the action of creating a symlink to block another process from starting. A regular file on the other hand is not guaranteed to be atomic..

Comment: .. so for example if you decide to implement a lock file using a text file. Process A decides to create a "lock.txt" file. The OS creates some data structures on disk. It starts writing the filename "loc" then right after it writs the letter "c" to disk process B runs. Process B decides to check if the file "lock.txt" exist. It sees it doesn't exist (only a file called "loc" exist). And it creates a file called "lock.txt". Now Process A runs. At this point both process A and process B believe they are the only ones running...

Comment: ... so the correct way to create a lock file is by creating a symlink

Comment: Note that you can use other files (eg. a JSON file or a csv file) to store actual data. Use the symlink to ensure that only one program can write to that file at any one time. Once you are done the process holding the lock can delete the lock file and let other processes have write access to them. You don't need to lock file reads, only writes.

Comment: ok so I will have to create a local lock file ( e.g. JSON ) and the code above creates a symlink to that file to ensure only the current process can write to it until the symlink got unlinked? The drawback would be that one must create a local file ( or via code ) and the benefit is that during the process no one else can modify it?

Comment: No. You create a symlink first. A symlink is a file. Kind of like what Windows call "shortcut" files. The code above will create a symlink to your node.js script (`argv[1]`). You could also choose to create a symlink to the node.js executable (eg. node.exe on Wondows) if you use `argv[0]`. The file you link to does not matter. What matters is if the symlink exist on disk or not. You are using the existence of the file to communicate between processes.

Comment: Also.. **DON'T** check if the file exist. Another process may run between the time you check and the time you create a symlink. Just try to create one and if it already exist the OS will throw an error. Use that error as a signal that another process is holding the lock. If you need multiple locks create multiple symlinks. The symlink file name indicates what kind of lock it is